# oci_fetch_array(): ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Получаемая ошибка в заголовке.

База данных oracle

Запрос

```sql
SELECT * FROM USERS;
```

USERS - view, а не таблица.

И USERS имеет 1 поле у которого в типе стоит ссылка на другую таблицу. В таблицах без такой штуки работает. Повлиять на структуру таблицы я не могу, так что надо как-то научиться с этим работать.

Comment: ну видимо что то типа `select * from table(select filed from USERS)` только конечно надо брать конкретное табличное значение из одной конкретной записи.

Answer (score 2):

`USERS` это так называемое объектное представление. Простейший пример:

```
create or replace type userName force is object (id number, name varchar2 (32))
/
create or replace type userList as table of userName; 
/
create table t1 as 
    select 1 id, 'user 1' memo from dual;
create table t2 as 
    select id userid, rownum id, 'name '||rownum name from t1 connect by level<=3;

create or replace view users as
    select t1.id, t1.memo, cast (multiset (
        select t2.id, t2.name from t2 where t2.userid=t1.id) as userList) names 
    from t1;
```

Получить данные из него обратно в реляционной форме следует так:

```
select u.memo, t.id, t.name 
from users u, table (u.names) t
/
MEMO           ID NAME                                         
------ ---------- ---------------------------------------------
user 1          1 name 1                                       
user 1          2 name 2                                       
user 1          3 name 3
```

Answer (score 0):

ну например, если вложенная таблица не нужна -  просто перечислить в запросе те поля, которые надо получить:
`select field1, field3, field3, ... fieldN from users;`

Comment: Безусловно это сработает. Более того мне пока так сделать и пришлось. Но это не решение проблемы а лишь способ её обойти. Пришлось ActiveRecord поддопилить что бы он так делал при Model::find()->all();

Comment: а вот это проблемное поле - это вложенная таблица (NESTED TABLE)? просто из задачи не совсем ясно - так как "ссылка на таблицу", это простой столбец, на который навешен foreign key,  и таких проблем вызывать, по идее, не должен.

Comment: Да, это NESTED TABLE